# Facebook needs 28 char long sha1 hash. Keytool generating 24 characters instead of 28

Tags: android, facebook, sha1, keytool

In my app there is a **facebook login**. I would like to **add an Android app to my facebook app** which needs a **hash generated with the keytool** from the keystore file.

I can successfully generate a 28 character long hash from my production key but if **I run the same command on my debug key, (which is the default android debug key) it only generates a 24 character long hash, which facebook does not let me input.**

---

I use this command in windows' default cmd:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   "C:\Users\myusernamehere\.android\debug.keystore" |
>   "D:\Programs\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary
>   |"D:\Programs\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

---

### In the picture you can see that facebook doesn't let me enter other than 28 char long hash.

[image]

### Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the openssl

use the openssl-0.9.8e version

select your OS architecture if it is 32 bit then select
openssl-0.9.8e X32

if your OS architecture is 64bit then select 
openssl-0.9.8e X64

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i used this openssl version https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/ and it works